# transformClassAndResourcWithProguardForRelease error when I try export signed apk file in android app with proguard enabled?

Tags: android, proguard, signed-apk

It is the first time that I am using the proguard with the android app so it is kind of confusing me. Here's scenario about my problem: I enable the proguard [in the gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBgs3.png) and I run it on my phone it is working perfectly (without any error) but if I want to generate signed apk file then it shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4LuM.png). Why I want to generate the signed apk file because I want to check whether the proguard obfuscating and optimizing my app or not by decompiling the apk file. Hence, My questions are: is there any way to check whether proguard is obfuscating and optimizing the app or not? and what is the problem with my generating signed apk file? 
 Here are the pictures of my proguard rules file: [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ6GQ.png), [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNNy2.png), [Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9zHu.png) and [Last one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nShLE.png).

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you got some warnings when running ProGuard in a release build. You should run the build with the -i flag and add also -verbose to your ProGuard rules to get a more verbose output.

If you decide to ignore the warnings, you can also add -ignorewarnings to your rules and ProGuard will continue executing regardless if it detects some problems that you should fix.